# Does the conversion from string to rune slice make a copy?

Tags: go, rune

I'm teaching myself Go from a C background.
The code below works as I expect (the first two `Printf()` will access bytes, the last two `Printf()` will access codepoints).

What I am not clear is if this involves any copying of data.

```
package main

import "fmt"

var a string

func main() {
    a = "èe"
    fmt.Printf("%d\n", a[0])
    fmt.Printf("%d\n", a[1])
    fmt.Println("")
    fmt.Printf("%d\n", []rune(a)[0])
    fmt.Printf("%d\n", []rune(a)[1])
}
```

In other words:

> does `[]rune("string")` create an array of runes and fill it with the runes corresponding to `"string"`, or it's just the compiler that figures out how to get runes from the string bytes?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It involves a copy because:

- strings are immutable; if the conversion `[]rune(s)` didn't make a copy, you would be able to index the rune slice and change the string contents
- a [`string`](https://golang.org/ref/spec#String_types) value is a *"(possibly empty) sequence of bytes"*, where `byte` is an alias of `uint8`, whereas a [`rune`](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Rune_literals) is a *"an integer value identifying a Unicode code point"* and an alias of `int32`. The types are not identical and even the lengths may not be the same:

```
    a = "èe"
    r := []rune(a)
    fmt.Println(len(a)) // 3 (3 bytes)
    fmt.Println(len(r)) // 2 (2 Unicode code points)
```

Answer (score 7):

It is not possible to turn []uint8 (i.e. a string) into []int32 ([an alias for []rune](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Numeric_types)) without allocating an array.

Also, [strings are immutable in Go](https://golang.org/ref/spec#String_types) but slices are not, so the conversion to both []byte and []rune must copy the string's bytes in some way or another.